# PHP variable in HTML Input tag causes markup validation error

Tags: php, html, validation

I am having an issue with markup validation which is caused by a php tag inside a form and don't know how to fix it. This is the line causing the issues:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Forward" value="<?php echo $Goto; ?>">
```

The validation errors are:

```
Error: No space between attributes.
At line 30, column 49
7900' colspan="5"><span style=

Error: Quote " in attribute name. Probable cause: Matching quote missing somewhere earlier.
At line 30, column 50
900' colspan="5"><span style='

Warning: Attribute 5" is not serializable as XML 1.0.
From line 28, column 2; to line 30, column 51
s"><br/>↩   <input type="hidden" name="Forward" value="<br />↩<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>↩<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span
```

And then about 30 stray end tags for tables. Most of the code in the error appears nowhere on the page and deleting the php echo makes it validate successfully. Let me know if any more info would help.

Comment: What is in `$Goto` ?

Comment: It's used for include "$Goto.php"; to redirect based on a post.
I haven't learned about rendering. Still a Uni student and they just want me to validate my assignments

Comment: Well, if `$Goto` includes a double-quote, then you can see that will confuse matters because your browser will see that as the end of the `value` attribute. What does that variable contain if you `var_dump()` it?

Comment: It contains the correct string, either CustomerList, OrderList or ProductDetails depending on what page the user was redirected from

Comment: Show us the rendered HTML.

Comment: It *looks* like there's an error in your `$Goto` script which is triggering XDebug ... which outputs a nice HTML error message ... which is breaking your HTML attribute value.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that or what that means. I can upload the full code to pastebin if that would be fine?

Comment: @CD001 Goto.php isn't a script, all it's doing is replacing include "$Goto.php"; to include "$CustomerList.php"; so it displays that page

Comment: Ok... well there's an error in `CustomerList.php` if that's what's being included; if you look at your value string `<br />↩<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice'...` <-- see that `xdebug-error` class? That implies that something has fallen over and XDebug is generating the output... and it's doing it where you `echo $Goto` - so whatever that `$Goto` variable is doing, that's triggering an error.

Comment: All of the $Goto pages do validate fine on their own, so it must be something to do with how the include works then. I might try to make it a separate page instead of an include and see if that works.

Tested and it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself, if anybody else ever has this issue make sure that your variable has a default value:

```
if (isset($_POST['Forward'])){
    $Goto = $_POST['Forward'];
}
else{
    $Goto = 'Login';
}
```